# Why didn't the UK want a return policy when negotiating Brexit?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, illegal-immigration

I've just watched [this video](https://youtu.be/2gUbMS_BufI) that shows that the rise of boat immigrants to the UK is because the UK didn't want a return policy. It seems as though it would have been very important to the UK to have one in order to stop the illegal immigration, but why didn't the UK want to have one?

Comment: You mean an *(illegal) immigrant* return policy?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The report the video references, *[Sea Change on Border Control: A Strategy for Reducing Small Boat Crossings in the English Channel](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4351994)* by Professor Thom Brooks suggests that the government "failed to anticipate the consequences for leaving the EU without a
returns arrangement in place" for two reasons:

1. The UK didn't make that much use of the EU return agreement (known as the Dublin III regulation) pre-Brexit. In 2018, for example, 5,510 outgoing transfer requests were made by the UK to various EU countries, of which 209 were accepted. During the same period, 1,215 migrants were transferred to the UK under the regulations, meaning that the UK was a net recipient of migrants under the agreement. Brooks argues in his report that the Home Office "failed to appreciate that the Dublin Regulation could exercise a deterrent effect" post-Brexit.
2. A view in the Home Office that there was no difference between irregular migration via lorry or other road vehicles, and irregular migration via small boats, and could be dealt with in a similar way to how this issue was tackled - through pre-entry checks.

I'm not sure the characterisation of the UK government's position as "not wanting to have a returns policy" is accurate, however. The report even points to various statements by Government defending its migration plan, concluding:

> These statements show that the Government sought an agreement on a new
> returns arrangement with the EU as part of its Brexit deal, but the UK
> failed to secure it before leaving the EU and so the UK was left
> without a plan and no assessment for what to expect without it. The
> consequences were presumably, and wrongly, thought non-consequential.

So the report seems to argue that although a migrant returns policy similar to Dublin III was sought, it took a back seat in negotiations compared to other priorities, for the reasons above.

Furthermore, the Commons Library research briefing *[Brexit: the end of the Dublin III Regulation in the UK](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/research-briefings/cbp-9031/)* states that the government proposed two draft agreements; "an agreement on the transfer of unaccompanied asylum-seeking children for family reunion purposes" and "a readmission agreement for accepting returns of irregularly residing UK/EU citizens and third country nationals", but that the EU rejected these agreements as outwith their negotiating mandate.

It's also perhaps worth pointing out that the author of the report - according to [his website](https://www.thombrooks.info/labour-party/) - is a Labour Party advisor, and chair of the Sedgefield Constituency Labour Party's Sedgefield Branch, and the report contains quite a large chunk dedicated to praising Labour's statements on the subject.

Comment: Can be please clarify why is it worth pointing out the last paragraph in your answer?

Comment: @Mocas I think it helps readers evaluate whether or not to treat the author of the report as an impartial observer.

Answer (score 23):

The UK government did propose two possible agreements for returning certain migrants, but to understand why they were not taken up by the EU you have to understand the brexit negotiation process.

The UK started in a weak position, and the EU immediately took control of the negotiation. The EU's priorities were rights for its own citizens, and protecting the single market. The UK government struggled to get agreement from its own parliament, resulting in things like the return of migrants being left on the table for agreement later.

After making the initial Withdrawal Agreement, the EU was keen to move on from wasting time on negotiations with the UK, and focus its energy elsewhere. While the issue may be important to the UK, it has little effect on the EU. There are also many other more pressing issues, like the Northern Ireland Protocol.

So essentially there is little interest on the EU side, and no leverage on the UK side.

There would also likely be issues for the UK, such as EU requirements that the asylum and immigration system that decides if migrants should be returned must be fair and subject to European Court of Justice (ECJ) rulings. The UK government seems very keen not to have anything to do with the ECJ, which is frequently blamed by the UK media for all manner of things.

Comment: It's also likely that sending illegal immigrants to Rwanda (or another developing nation) would be a a *far* better deterrent, similar to how Australia's cooperation with Nauru is extremely effective. See https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/77201/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-plan-to-send-those-seeking-asylum-in-the-uk-to

Comment: Its probably also fair to say that the UK is likely to get a better deal in these kinds of 0-leverage diplomatic negotiations after a fair bit more time passes, and the EU politicians who are still sore over the UK's behavior during the Brexit negotiations, as well as the UK politicians who were responsible for it, have cycled out of office.

Comment: @T.E.D. it's probably the opposite. As time goes by things will get worse and the UK more desperate.

Comment: @user - Perhaps, but they *already* have no leverage. At least at some point they can hope the EU would see fit to help them out as a neighborly gesture. That's just not a possibility right now.